# How to use JUnit in eclipse with groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, junit

I am new to JUnit, following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) but need some suggestions and understanding on my testcase

I have some xmls (3MB-6MB each) in a folder, for each xml I need to test some tags whether they contain some value or not and sometimes match that value to a specific result.

So how can I execute all my @Test functions inside a loop, for each test? Do I need to normally call the @Test Functions (coz they are called automatically) inside loop?

Please help me undertand JUnit with this context. Thanks

Junit testcase

```
public class SystemsCheck {

    def fileList

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        def dir = new File("E:\\temp\\junit\\fast")
        fileList = []

        def newFile=""
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
            fileList << file
          }

        fileList.each {
            //how should i test all @Test with it.text
            println it.text
          }     
    }

    @Test 
    void testOsname(){
        NixSystems ns=new NixSystems()
        /*checking if tag is not empty*/
        //assertEquals("Result","",ns.verifyOsname())
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultiply(){
        NixSystems ns=new NixSystems()
        assertEquals("Result", 50, ns.multiply(10, 5))
    }

}

class NixSystems {

    public def verifyOsname(xml){
        return processXml( xml, '//client/system/osname' )
    }

    public def multiply(int x, int y) {
        return x * y;
    }


    def processXml( String xml, String xpathQuery ) {
        def xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
        def builder     = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
        def inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( xml.bytes )
        def records     = builder.parse(inputStream).documentElement
        xpath.evaluate( xpathQuery, records )
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit has dedicated feature for this kind of tests - [Parameterized JUnit Tests](http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/writing-a-parameterized-junit-test/).
This basically do what you've already done but in concise, standarized manner.

Below is code for `Java` - can be easily converted to `Groovy`.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestCase {
    private Type placeholder1;
    private Type placeholder2;
    ...
    public TestCase(Param1 placeholder1, Param2 placeholder2, ...) {
        this.placeholder1 = placeholder1;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[][]> data() {
        //prepare data
        //each row is one test, each object in row is placeholder1/2... for this test case 
    }

    @Test
    public void yourTest() {...}
}
```

In JavaDocs of [org.junit.runners.Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) you can find example of Fibonnaci numbers test.